# Perl : how to apply two codes on csv file

Tags: perl

I have many csv files that I need to clean ( replace ponctuation by space and replace certain words by others...) My csv files have two columns and in each one I replace some caracters by others. For exemple, in the first column I replace ; by xxx and in the second column I replace ; by ppp. To do that, I have two perl codes in regex and I slice one csv file on two files : file 1 = first column and file 2 = second column and I run the code for the first columns on the file of the first colums ....
It's not a good way at all :s !!!

So how can I have one code in which the first condition run on the first column and the second condition on the second column of the SAME file ?

CSV example :
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berenguer_de_Cru%C3%AFlles  Berenguer de Cruïlles
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berenguer_de_Cru%C3%AFlles  Berenguer de Cruïlles

The IRI is the first column and the names are in the second one.

Perl code in regex for the first column :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(IN,$ARGV[0]);
open(OUT,">RES_xxx.txt");
while(my $l = <IN>)
{
 chomp($l);
     $l =~ s/http:\/\//_/g;
     $l =~ s/,/vvv/g;
     $l =~ s/"/=/g;
     $l =~ s/'/#/g;
     $l =~ s/\(/ééé/g;
     $l =~ s/\)/èèè/g;
     $l =~ s/%/zzz/g;

     print OUT "$l\n";
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

Perl code in regex for the second column :

```
   #! usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    open(IN,$ARGV[0]);
    open(OUT,">RES_xxx.txt");
    while(my $l = <IN>)
    {
     chomp($l);
     $l =~ s/\(.+\)/ /g;
     $l =~ s/'/ /g;
     $l =~ s/"/ /g;
     $l =~ s/,/ /g;
     $l =~ s/\./ /g;
     $l =~ s/:/ /g;
     $l =~ s/;/ /g;
     $l =~ s/!/ /g;
     $l =~ s/\?/ /g;
     $l =~ s/-/ /g;
     $l =~ s/_/ /g;
     $l =~ s/{/ /g;
     $l =~ s/}/ /g;
     $l =~ s/\+/ /g;
     $l =~ s/=/ /g;

     print OUT "$l\n";
    }
    close(IN);
    close(OUT);
```

Thank you !

Comment: post your code and sample data from your csv.

Comment: please [edit] the example into your post.

Comment: You know that you can use a character class instead of a bunch of nearly identical substitutions: `s/['",.:;?_{}+=-]/ /g`

Comment: Thanks, I did that but it was between parenthesis so it didn't worked !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by parsing your file in two steps:

1. on the first step, you replace the `;` in the first column of the original file;
2. on the second step, you replace the `;` in the second column on the output of the first step.

This should be easily done from your current solution: I suppose you have a regex to match the first column and the second column. You can simply change those regex so that instead of matching the first or second columns, they replace within that column.

If you provide more details about your files and how you currently split the two columns, I might provide some concrete example.

EDIT:

Since it seems that you only have two columns and each does not contain any commas, you could do like this:

1. parse the file line by line;
2. split the line at the `,` (separator between the columns);
3. on each part you got at step 2, apply the regex to replace what you want.

E.g.:

```
my $file = 'file.csv';
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  my ($firstCol, $secondCol) = split(/,/, $line);
  $firstCol =~ s/;/xxx/g;
  $secondCol =~ s/;/yyy/g;
  print "$firstCol, $secondCol\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't have regex to match the columns. I split the file by coping the first column on anathor file, the same for the second column.

Comment: You mean, you slice the file in 2 columns by hand? Could your provide some lines of your csv file?

Comment: In the first column I have an IRI and the second I have its value

Comment: in both columns I have punctuations (,;'...) so what can I use as split parameter ?

Comment: Do I need special package to excute that. I tried it but I got this error : Global symbol "$firstCol" requires explicit package name at Clean_DBP.pl line 13.
Global symbol "$secondCol" requires explicit package name at Clean_DBP.pl line 13. Am working on Linux

Comment: You do not need packages; I forgot parenthesis (check my edit). As to punctuation: are you sure you only have 2 cols? Is the `,` part of the URL? I am not sure I understand...

Comment: Yes, I have 2 columns. In the first one, it contains IRIs with ponctuation like in this one : http://dbpedia.org/resource/Al_Freeman,_Jr. and in the second column, it contains names and some are writen in this way : André Abadie (rugby à XV, 1932) ; or this way Didier d'Yd, d'Yd Didier .

Comment: Is it safe to say that the first blank character is a separator between the two columns? If you have `,` characters as part of the values, either  they are escaped, of the values are quoted (using `"` or `'`).